# NameError: name 'dict1' is not defined ? why this error is coming?

Tags: python, dictionary, variables, global

This code is saying dict1 is not defined. I have defined the dict globally. It should be accessible inside a function. Please guide.

In this code i am trying to add key value pair to dict1, if key-value pair is not present in the dict else it will fetch the value from dict.

```
def find_sum(num_str):
    sum1=0
    for i in num_str:
        sum1+=int(i)
    return sum1
    

def find_ten_substring(num_str):
    list1=[]
   
    for i in range(2,len(num_str)+1):
        for j in range(0, i):
            if(i!=j ):
                x=num_str[j:i]
                if(x in dict1):
                    if(dict1[x]==10):
                        list1.append(x)
                elif(x not in dict1):
                    y=find_sum(x)
                    
                    if(y==10):
                        dict1[x]=y 
                        list1.append(x)
    
    return list1
    
    #Remove pass and write your logic here
    return list1
    
dict1={}
num_str="2825302"
print("The number is:",num_str)
result_list=find_ten_substring(num_str)
print(result_list)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce.  The code you have provided here did not produce a `Traceback`, and the output of `['28', '82', '253', '2530', '5302']` was produced.

Comment: Yep, It doesn't raise any error.

Comment: Works for me also. Try moving `dict1={}` to the top of the script. If you still receive an error, please provide the traceback.

Answer (score 1):

The code works perfectly fine for me in python 3.7.3.

`The number is: 2825302`

`['28', '82', '253', '2530', '5302']`

this is the output I have received

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the error.  Better practice is to pass mutable objects as parameters to functions.  Changed `find_ten_substring()` to take additional parameter

```
def find_sum(num_str):
    sum1 = 0
    for i in num_str:
        sum1 += int(i)
    return sum1


def find_ten_substring(num_str, dict1):
    list1 = []

    for i in range(2, len(num_str) + 1):
        for j in range(0, i):
            if (i != j):
                x = num_str[j:i]
                if (x in dict1):
                    if (dict1[x] == 10):
                        list1.append(x)
                elif (x not in dict1):
                    y = find_sum(x)

                    if (y == 10):
                        dict1[x] = y
                        list1.append(x)

    return list1

    # Remove pass and write your logic here
    return list1


dict1 = {}
num_str = "2825302"
print("The number is:", num_str)
result_list = find_ten_substring(num_str, dict1)
print(result_list, dict1)
```